# Does "The role of a client for a service" sound natural to you?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I have been trying to better understand the usage of prepositions lately. Today I want to explain a relative complex idea to a native speaker. I want to sound natural but I am not sure how to connect three nouns correctly with prepositions.

I have three nouns here, the role, the client, and the service. All I am trying to say is that "the role of a client for a service" is defined as the "partnerlink", but I am not sure if I should say **"for a service" or "for the service" or "to a service" or even "of a service".**

I believe I should use **role of a client** where role is a property of the client. The role is something belongs to the client. **But I am not sure which preposition to use between the client and the service.** To *or* of *or* for?

Comment: Is this some obscure technical / computing context? In general, the ***customer*** is the one who adopts "the role of client" (or just ***is*** the client) for some "service" (which in most cases he ***pays*** for)..

Comment: It isn't even clear what "The role of a client for a service" means.

Comment: ***of*** and ***for*** are [the most common prepositions](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+client+%2A+the+service&year_start=1960&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Ca%20client%20%2A%20the%20service%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ba%20client%20of%20the%20service%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20client%20for%20the%20service%3B%2Cc0) for this context. But ***too, with** and ***on*** (and probably some other alternatives) wouldn't be ridiculous. Or just sidestep the issue and refer to *the role of **service client***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. Yes... It is some O*racle technology, where you have a client calls a service, and both of them are software components.  The client has an attribute called the "client role" or the "partner role".  More than likely, that client will be the only client calls the service but over and over and over again.

Comment: Your context isn't much to do with "normal English". I've recently been learning the QT software development system, and I must admit it took me a little while to get used to the sometimes peculiar ways they use the word "role". And "client" in computing client/server contexts is almost completely meaningless to people who aren't familiar with the jargon, despite the fact that almost all native Anglophones would recognize the meanings of those words in *other* contexts without a second thought.

Comment: @WeatherVane. Aha!! You have a point. It is just a randomly defined concept I was trying to explain to a co-worker, where you have two software components being the client, and the other being the service. The client has a few attributes and it calls the service over and over. One of the attributes of the client is the role of the client. The role is self defined and can be literally anything. The name of the role is called the "partner role". I am just trying to explain what "partner role" is.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. I guess I should ask a more general question then: When to use "to a service" vs "for a service" vs "of a service". I just googled "a client to a service" and "a client for a service". Both of them returned many results but I can't really tell the differences between the two by looking at the results.

Comment: The usual pairing is client / **server**.

Comment: The ***a/the** service* choice simply depends on whether you've already contextually identified a specific  *(**the**)* service. And the choice of preposition isn't important, as pointed out before. But that won't help anyone who doesn't understand what you're getting at with "**partner** role" (which I certainly don't).